# Adding "required" fields to forms in rails and throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

Pretty much what is written in the title.

I want to do client side validation of forms in rails, so that whenever a user does not enter some "required" fields, it throws errors and do not submit the form at all (as opposed to doing that on the server side and redirect_to :back).

Any examples on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look 
[http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations/%22Client%20Side%20Validation%22)

Showing validation errors inline as the user is filling out the form can lead to a better use experience. Learn how to do this using the Client Side Validations gem.